# How do you reset the Google AppEngine Datastore Quota Exceeded condition?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-quotas

If you have a application that exceeds that Datastore quota of 1 Gig (Master/Slave configuration) How do you clear the condition?

I have an application called "parking-helper" and it has a Total Stored Data 100% used message.

But I've deleted 99% of the data (a few days ago) cleared the indexes, 
vacuumed the indexes and cleared the memcache and also waited for at 
least 2 reset cycles and yet the datastore still says 100% used.

The datastore admin shows that the datastore does not add up to more than a 
meg.

I know that memcache and indexes count also.  It would be nice to see the sizes of these in the Datastore Admin view (but currently we cannot see these values).  But I believe I cleared them also.

How can I reset this application without the drastic measure of deleting and re-creating which means I'd have to pick another application id and re-create all the other data.

Thanks,
Ralph

Comment: Please try to delete all versions on your app. If it didn't affect, I think a good way is delete your app and create new other app... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's usually just a matter of waiting. And it looks like your quota is under 100% now.